# Unexpected Crash when Handling Alamofire DataRequest Response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I get a crash in Alamofire on iOS devices (iPhone XR, iPhone 13Pro), but don't get on the simulator or when I run as a Mac App.
All iOS devices (both Simulator and Actual devices) all on iOS16.4.x

It always occurs at the same point in DataRequest.response(queue: DispatchQueue = .main, completionHandler: @escaping (AFDataResponse<Data?>) -> Void)

Has anyone else had anything similar or know what might cause this?

[Strack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHhNF.png)

[CPU and Memory look fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbItr.png)

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f213fc0)

```
    public func response(queue: DispatchQueue = .main, completionHandler: @escaping (AFDataResponse<Data?>) -> Void) -> Self {
        appendResponseSerializer {
            // Start work that should be on the serialization queue.
            let result = AFResult<Data?>(value: self.data, error: self.error)
            // End work that should be on the serialization queue.

            self.underlyingQueue.async {
                let response = DataResponse(request: self.request,
                                            response: self.response,
                                            data: self.data,
                                            metrics: self.metrics,
                                            serializationDuration: 0,
                                            result: result)

                self.eventMonitor?.request(self, didParseResponse: response)

                self.responseSerializerDidComplete { queue.async { completionHandler(response) } }
            }
        }

        return self
    }
```

Crash occurs on this line: self.responseSerializerDidComplete { queue.async { completionHandler(response) } }

Alamofire Version 5.7.1

Comment: can you put a breakpoint there and check if any object becomes null?

Comment: Thanks @Md.Sulayman. I have checked that, and there nothing is null.

Comment: This is most likely a crash within your completion handler that isn't properly breaking in the handler.